# Symfony2 project on local server

Tags: php, symfony, permissions, localserver

I am trying to run a Symfony2 project on my local server after downloading it from the FTP. I keep getting this error when running the server:

> **Warning**: require(app_dev.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>   /Users/bogdan/Sites/httpdocs/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/router_dev.php
>   on line 36

I am running everything on developer mode.

Comment: I see you've tagged this with [permissions] - PHP would throw an error like: `failed to open stream: Permission denied` if it were a permissions issue. Does everything else in the vendor folder exist?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest to read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html firstly.

Anyway I think that you run `console` from a bad path. You have to run `app/console server:run`. It means that you have to be in a root directory of your project.

```
cd my_symfony2_project
php app/console server:run
```

Comment: If this were the problem, I'd expect an error message of: `Could not open input file: app/console`

Comment: I think the previous message it's clear enough. It says the same with aditional information.

Comment: I am running the console from the right folder. I have previously installed several symfony projects(from zero) and they work.